# Azure: SQL Compact possible?

Tags: azure

I have a RESTful service running on azure. Currently, it has zero persistence. (It is just a REST gateway to another api.) I run it in a single, minimal Azure instance, and expect this will handle all the load this will ever get.

I now need to add some very lightweight persistence to it. A simple table, of 40-200 rows, eight data columns. The data is very static.

Doing the whole SQL Azure thing seems big overkill for my needs.

My thoughts have been to use:

1. An XML file, and load it into memory, as the db. XML file is
   deployed with code.
2. Some better way to deploy XML, so it can be
   rolled out/updated easier
3. SQL Compact (can I do this on Azure?)
4. __*_* ?

What is the right path here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server Compact would need to store its data somewhere in persistent manner, so you would need to sync it regularly to a persistent storage and that's a lot of extra work and I have no idea how to do that reliably, so it's likely not a very good idea.

For your simple table the Azure Table Storage might be just enough. If that's not enough then SQL Azure is the next choice.

Comment: Table Storage seems like an excellent fit. Further: If any of your individual data objects is too large to fit into a table entity, you can store it in a blob and point to it from your table row.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the XML file as your store, there is no harm it it, rather this is a very easy and cost efficient solution, but there is a catch. As you mentioned currently you are using only azure instance, in this case you can store the XML file in your `App_Data`, but if in future if you want to shift to 2 azure instance, you will have to replicate the `App_Data` folder. In other words you will need to keep `App_Data` folder in sync.

### **Suggestion**

Instead of storing file in `App_Data` store it in `BLOB`, you can retrieve it using `WebClient` and the store it in memory.

**Pros**: The advantage of `BLOB` is, you don't have to sync it.

**Cons**: There is a cost associated on the number of transactions you can make. This will depend upon how many times you update the file.

### **Summary**

- If you are going to work with only one Azure Instance, use `App_Data`
- More than one Azure Instance, use `BLOB` with no syncing or use `App_Data` with sync.
- Do not use Azure Table, as `BLOB` is the designated store provided for this purpose only.

**EDIT**

From [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/windowsazuredata/thread/ddbdbce1-8f37-4a47-9947-0d7cb3eeedcd) post

> As far as I know, Windows Azure does not support SQL Compact Edition. SQL Compact Edition stores data in file system which will not be synchronized in multiple instances (a web role may be deployed to more than one instance. An instance is similar to a virtual machine). And files stored in file system will lost when the instance is restarted or reimaged.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I'd go with this. An xml file stored as a blob and retrieved on role statup would suit your needs perfectly. There's also Azure Table storage if the data could fuctuate slightly and there's a need to change changes between instances and restarts.